# Inject an Angular service into an exported function?

Tags: angular, typescript, function, dependency-injection, angular-services

I have the following exported function (out of class) that is defined in my AppComponent:

```
export function multiTranslateHttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new MultiTranslateHttpLoader(http, [
    {prefix: './assets/i18n/default/', suffix: '.json'},
    {prefix: './assets/i18n/bc/', suffix: '.json'}
  ]);
}
```

This is then used within the import arrays in the AppModule in this way:

```
TranslateModule.forRoot ({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: multiTranslateHttpLoaderFactory,
    deps: [HttpClient]
  }
}),
```

I would need a way to use my AuthService within the exported function, since I need certain properties to implement logic.

Is there a possibility for that?

For example, I would like to use my authService in this way:

```
export function multiTranslateHttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  let bc = this.authService.activeBusinessCase$.getValue();
  if(bc){
    ...
  }else{
    return new MultiTranslateHttpLoader(http, [
      {prefix: './assets/i18n/default/', suffix: '.json'},
      {prefix: './assets/i18n/bc/', suffix: '.json'}
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not add it to the `deps` list and the factory parameter list, then?

Comment: Hmm, I don't get it..

Comment: Well, you see how you're injecting the HttpClient into it? Just *do that again* with the service.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nothing easier.

```
export function multiTranslateHttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient, auth: AuthService) {
  // add AuthService logic

  return new MultiTranslateHttpLoader(http, [
    {prefix: './assets/i18n/default/', suffix: '.json'},
    {prefix: './assets/i18n/bc/', suffix: '.json'}
  ]);
}
```

and pass it as dependency

```
TranslateModule.forRoot ({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: multiTranslateHttpLoaderFactory,
    deps: [HttpClient, AuthService]
  }
}),
```

Comment: Seems to work. But I do not need to write my function back inside the AppModule right? Because I would like to keep it in the AppComponent, so my AppModule is clean.

Comment: ehm. The function location is all up to you. Nobody restricts you in that

Answer (score 2):

Additional to this solution, you can also make use of the Angular's Injector API.

[Follow the docs here](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector)